# Excel-VBA error getting oppStatLoc

Tags: excel, vba

So, I am getting an error in this line:

```
If Sheets(2).Cells(j, oppStatLoc).Value = OppStat Then
```

The program runs but then after it reaches a certain row it stops and lags. Then the error 1004 pops out. Here is the code.

Code:

```
Function getOppStat(OppStat As String)
        'For testing Purposes
        Dim paramList
        Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, currentRow As Long, oppStatLoc As Long

        lastRow = Sheets("Parameter").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = Sheets("Parameter").Range("XFD3").End(xlToLeft).Column
        currentRow = 2 'Sheets("OppStat").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'Set Up Headerz
        For i = 1 To lastCol
            Sheets("Parameter").Cells(3, i).Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets("OppStat").Cells(1, i)
        Next i

        'Look for OppStat Column
        For i = 1 To lastCol
            If Sheets("Parameter").Cells(3, i).Value = "Opportunity Status" Then
                oppStatLoc = i
            End If
        Next i

        'Set Up Valuez
        For j = 4 To lastRow
            If Sheets(2).Cells(j, oppStatLoc).Value = OppStat Then
                For k = 1 To lastCol
                    Sheets(2).Cells(j, k).Copy _
                        Destination:=Sheets(3).Cells(currentRow, k)
                Next k
                currentRow = currentRow + 1
            End If

        Next j

    End Function
```

what could be the problem?
the value of lastRow is 4213.

Comment: Add a watch on the `oppStatLoc` variable and see if it is returning acceptable results. It can't be equal to 0 which will happen if `"Opportunity Status"` isn't found. Also you are not returning any value in `getOppStat` considering you're using a function. If you don't need to return value, use `Sub` procedure instead.

Comment: what do u mean add a watch man? can u post the code? not familiar with all the methods and functions.

Comment: It is under `Debug` tab on your *VBE Editor*. You use it to monitor the value of a certain variable. Or you can simple add this line after your 2nd `For` loop. `Debug.Print oppStatLoc`. This will print the value of the variable on your immediate window. To view the *Immediate Window*, press **CTRL+G**.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if i > lastCol? I suggest to construct your loop as follows.

```
For i = lastCol to 1 step -1
    If Sheets("Parameter").Cells(3, i).Value = "Opportunity Status" Then
        oppStatLoc = I
        exit for
    End If
Next i
```

This loop will set I = 0 if a match isn't found. You should add a test, like `If i Then` and determine what to do it it fails (meaning i = 0)